# iOS Push Notifications for an app signed with different certificates from different dev accounts

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

If I had two developer accounts and generated APN SSL certificates from both accounts for the same bundle ID (com.example.app), would it be possible to send push notifications to the same app using both SSL certificates? In other words, could Account B send notifications to an app signed with Account A if it had a SSL certificate with the right bundle ID and the device token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go in the developer portal and try creating a new Apple Push Notification service SSL certificate, you will see that you need to pick a single target app based on the **App ID** not Bundle ID.

An App ID looks like a bundle ID but starts with a generated sequence of letters and numbers, e.g., `52EWJKLRW2342.com.example.app`.  That prefix is unique to your team and app  so Account A and Account B could not both generate apps with the same App ID or push certificates pointing to the same App ID.

If this were not the case, prior to iOS7 when all apps got the same device token, you could imagine the following attack:

1. An attacker buys/steals a bunch of device tokens from a popular app's servers (e.g., Candy Crush).
2. The attacker then sets up a bundle ID and push certificate for a target app (e.g., com.facebook.facebook).
3. The attacker then sends a ton of messages to this target app, either defaming it or exploiting a mechanic of the app to cause it to open content (e.g., the notification opens a temporary Facebook page selling viagra).

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought too and wanted to verify since the APN documentation always referred to the Bundle ID and didn't really mention the App ID. Where does the App ID verification occur (APN servers or device)?

Comment: Apple servers should be using your push certificate to select which App ID to send the message to (and validate the device token).  They probably then send the App ID in the message to the client device.